# Sorting a list test

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

I have one more assignment for the semester.  It involves testing to see if a list is sorted or not.  Given a list, say a list of numbers, test to see if the list is sorted and return a True value or if not return a False value.  I have to create a function that does the testing.

I was thinking of using an if statement to test for True.  Here is my code so far:

```
def my_list (list):
    list=[]
    if list.sorted() == True:
        print ("The list is sorted: True")
    else:
        print ("The list is unsorted: False")

list = input ("What is your list: ")
```

I am not sure this is the way to go. In fact I am not sure that you can test the sorted method in this manner.  The assignment is due today and I am sure the time pressure is not letting me see the obvious.

Any help, even just sending me in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Don't leave your homework until the last moment. A list is sorted if nothing changes when you sort it.

Comment: never ever call a variable "list". 'list' a type name in Python

Comment: you can input a *list* using input(). input() returns a string...how shall that ever become a list?

Comment: Also, go through your old questions and improve your accept rating. 0% on five questions with at least one legit answer isn't reasonable.

Comment: The blueprint is obvious: you iterate over all elements and check if the current element is larger than the previous one...put this into code...we don't write it for you....

Comment: I am new to the site.  I am not sure how to improve my accept score.  I would be happy to address this issue if someone will tell me how or where I can find the answer on how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't do the homework for you, but I'll provide some hints.

There are several possible approaches:

1. You could sort the list and see if the sorting changes the order of elements.
2. You could iterate over the list, comparing each element to its immediate predecessor.

The first method is arguably easier to implement, whereas the second is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, I was not asking for you to do the homework.  I have been looking at this so long, I could not see an answer. Thanks for some suggestions on how to approach the problem.

Comment: Please add the following to the bottom of your assignment: "Solved with major help from Stackoverflow"

Comment: Again thanks for the help.  I got it working by comparing a sorted version of the list to the original list.  If the two list are equal I get a True and if they are not I get a False.  Thanks again for all the help.